# How do I use TortoiseSVN for this? It doesn't work

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ssh

```
svn co svn+ssh://174.13.24.17/home/svn/dragon-repos/
```

That's how I check out on my linux box.
I would like to checkout on my Windows machine. But, Tortoise SVN asks me for the "URL" (I don't have a **URL**...I just do it like that, above)

Can't I just run the command line to check out, like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn+ssh://174.13.24.17/home/svn/dragon-repos/` **is** a URL. You may need something like PuTTY for the ssh bit though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the [TortoiseSVN SSH HowTo](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto).

In particular, before you can use TortoiseSVN with SSH, you need to do the steps in the `SSH key generation and connection check (client)` section of this document.